# Search ancestor-or-self axis to find first non empty attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath, wireshark

In working with WireShark's pdml output (definition here:  http://www.nbee.org/doku.php?id=netpdl:pdml_specification) I'm attempting to transform a larger document of the same structure below to the sample further below:

Original XML:

```
<packet>
    <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General Information" size="308">
        <field name="num" pos="0" show="2574" showname="Number" value="a0e" size="308"/>
        <!-- more field tags here -->
    </proto>
    <proto name="ip" showname="Internet Protocol Version 4" size="0" pos="0">
        <field name="" show="This is a fake entry created from the metadata" size="308" pos="0" value="">
            <field name="ip.src" showname="Source: 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)" size="0" pos="0" show="1.2.3.4"/>
            <field name="ip.src2" showname="Source: 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)" hide="yes" size="0" pos="0" show="1.2.3.4"/>
            <!-- more field tags here -->
        </field>
        <!-- more field tags here -->
    </proto>
    <!-- more proto tags here -->
</packet>
```

Expected/Hopeful/Eventual Output:

```
<packet>
    <geninfo>
        <pos>0</pos>
        <showname>General Information</showname>
        <size>308</size>
        <num>
            <pos>0</pos>
            <show>2574</show>
            <showname>Number</showname>
            <value>a0e</value>
            <size>308</size>
        </num>
        <!-- more transformed field tags here -->
    </geninfo>
    <ip>
        <showname>Internet Protocol Version 4</showname>
        <size>0</size>
        <pos>0</pos>
        <ip>
            <show>This is a fake entry created from the metadata</show>
            <size>308</size>
            <pos>0</pos>
            <ip.src>
                <showname>Source: 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)</showname>
                <size>0</size>
                <pos>0</pos>
                <show>1.2.3.4</show>
            </ip.src>
            <!-- more transformed field tags here -->
        </ip>
        <!-- more transformed field tags here -->
    </ip>
    <!-- more transformed proto tags here -->
</packet>
```

Current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(@hide)]">
        <xsl:variable name="nameAttr" select="ancestor-or-self::*[@name][1]/@name!=''"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$nameAttr}">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*[name(.)!='name' and .!='']">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xst:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This skips all the tags with a hide attribute and moves the remaining tags' non-name attributes to sub tags of a new element created with the name attribute value while skipping the non-name attributes with empty string values.  In cases where the name attribute value is an empty string I intended to use the ancestor-or-self axis to find the first non empty name attribute value recursively searching through the ancestors knowing that every proto tag will have a non empty name attribute value if the search goes that far.

Any help with the syntax for getting the first ancestor-or-self non empty attribute name value (it currently returns the boolean value of whether or not @name != '') and any xslt stylistic/good practices comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working through what you have, I came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/packet">
        <packet>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </packet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proto[not(@hide)]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@name != '']">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"  />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@name = '']">
        <xsl:element name="{ancestor::*[@name != ''][1]/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[name() != 'name']">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Relevant to your original question, here's the XPath to get the ancestor with a non-empty @name:

```
<xsl:element name="{ancestor::*[@name != ''][1]/@name}">
```

But you do need a little restructuring to make this work in a maintainable way - try to think in terms of using templates more than for-each loops - it'll give you a more modular and flexible design.  In the above stylesheet, there's a template to match the root node (/packet), proto nodes that don't have a hide attribute, field nodes that have a filled in name, field nodes that don't, and attributes that aren't a 'name' attribute.

Comment: I thought if statements were the grand no-no of XSLT but if for each loops are also included on the list that's fine.  The solution above works but has two side effects I'm trying to avoid, when the current tag has a non empty name attribute it is duplicated as the value of the tag post transform and non name attributes with empty string values are included again.  I fixed the latter by adding (and .!='') to the last template match but haven't figured out the former yet.

Comment: Add another template to match `@name` tags that have a value:     `<xsl:template match="@*[name() = 'name']" />`.  This will prevent the preprocessor from copying the text automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is

```
<xsl:variable name="nameAttr" select="ancestor-or-self::*[@name != ''][1]"/>
```

To see why this will work, you need to understand the way XPath's general comparison operators work.

`A != value` actually means "of all the nodes selected by A, there is at least one that is not equal to value."

On an element that has no `@name` attribute, there will be no nodes selected by the subexpression `@name`, and so the `!=` general comparison will fail. On an element that has a `@name` attribute whose value is the empty string, the comparison again will fail, because there is only one node selected by `@name`, and it's equal to `''`. On an element that has a non-empty `@name` attribute, the comparison will succeed.

Also, it looks like you don't want

```
           <xsl:element name="{@name}">
```

but rather

```
           <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
```

In other words, you want the name of the "fake entry" element to be the name of the source attribute, not the value of the `name` attribute. Right? (And anyway, since you're in a `for-each` that's selecting an attribute, the current node is an attribute, so `@name` will be unable to select anything, because an attribute node can't have an attribute.)

Comment: In copying this over by hand I was bound to have at least one error, the edit now has name="name()" which I think reflects part of what is mentioned above.  I had tried the "ancestor-or-self::*[@name != ''][1]" before posting and got "An empty sequence is not allowed as the @name attribute of element" using the net.sf.saxon translator, are more templates needed to match each case in terms of when the comparison succeeds or fails?

Comment: Got it correct it the edit but not the comment, name="{name()}" was originally in the transform.  Just to clarify the <ip> for the <show>"This is a fake ..."</show> is the parent's name attribute value (in this case a proto tag), the <ip.src> tag is not involved in the ancestor-or-self search.  I wasn't sure what was meant by "source attribute" mentioned above.

Comment: By "source attribute" I meant e.g. the `show` attribute in `<field name="" show="This ...">` which is selected as the current node by one iteration of the `for-each`.

Comment: @jsonsini: Regarding your comment about the error ... this is not because of a problem in the XPath expression; that's working as designed. However the top-level element (`<packet>`) matches your template, but neither it nor any ancestor has a @name. So the stylesheet tries to output an element with no name. Yes, another template would help solve that problem: a template that matches `"packet"`, outputs a packet element, and recursively applies templates to the contents (look up "identity template").

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide my final solution (almost completely based on Dan Field's answer) and couldn't fit it in a comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*">
    <xsl:template match="packet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[(name()='proto' or name()='field') and not(@hide)]">
        <xsl:element name="{ancestor-or-self::*[@name!=''][1]/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[name()!='name' and .!='']">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[name()='name']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```